# Have Python 2.7 functions remember value and not reference? Closure Weirdness

Tags: python, functional-programming, scope, closures

I'm trying to return from a function a list of functions, each of which uses variables from the outside scope. This isn't working. Here's an example which demonstrates what's happening:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(lambda x: x+i)
a[1](1) # returns 10, where it seems it should return 2
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get around it in python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `i` refers to the same variable each time, so `i` is 9 in all of the lambdas because that's the value of `i` at the end of the loop. Simplest workaround involves a default argument:

```
lambda x, i=i: x+i
```

This binds the value of the loop's `i` to a local variable `i` at the lambda's definition time.

Another workaround is to define a lambda that defines another lambda, and call the first lambda:

```
(lambda i: lambda x: x+i)(i)
```

This behavior makes a little more sense if you consider this:

```
def outerfunc():

    def innerfunc():
        return x+i

    a = []
    for i in range(10):
        a.append(innerfunc)
    return a
```

Here, `innerfunc` is defined once, so it makes intuitive sense that you are only working with a single function object, and you would not expect the loop to create ten different closures. With a lambda it doesn't *look* like the function is defined only once, it looks like you're defining it fresh each time through the loop, but in fact it is functionally the same as the the long version.

Comment: Huh. Is there really no way to just let each lambda hold on to its own value? I thought this was the entire point of closure.

Comment: @Chironex, closure is on variable name not value

Comment: Is this the case for all programming languages which claim to feature closure?

Comment: @Chironex - it is their point, but it doesn't work the way you think it does! :)

Comment: @Chironex - nope, a closure encloses the present scope including variables. I just faced the same issue last week :-) Glad to see this workaround which is much better than mine.

Comment: Added some further explanation.

Comment: `(lambda i: lambda x: x+i)(i)` +1, this is the general way to do this.

Comment: @kindall: your extended explanation reminds me of the problem some people encounter when trying to use an empty list as a default argument for a function.

Comment: Is that "i=i" creating a new i withing the scope of the lambda definition and giving it the value of the outer i? What's actually going on there?

Comment: You're binding the local name `i` (local to the lambda) to the value of `i` in the loop's scope.

Comment: @phkahler: You are assigning a default value to a parameter of a function, that is being newly defined. The value will then be stored in the function object, rather than employ lexical scoping rules.

Answer (score 4):

Because i isn't getting evaluated when you define the anonymous function (lambda expression) but when it's called. You can see this by adding `del i` before `a[1](1)`: you'll get `NameError: global name 'i' is not defined` on the `a[1](1)` line.

You need to fix the value of i into the lambda expression every time, like so:

```
a = [lambda x, i=i: x+i for i in range(10)]
a[1](1) # returns 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, more general solution - also without lambdas:

```
import operator
from functools import partial
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(partial(operator.add, i))
a[1][(1) # returns 2
```

The key aspect here is [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: `partial(operator.add, i)` is equivalent to `(lambda i: lambda *args, **kwargs: operator.add(i, *args, **kwargs))()` but this is definitely prettier and built in functions are better than lambda expression where possible. I wouldn't say this is without lambdas though: it will still involve a function definition of some type if the operation is at all complicated.

Comment: I think there should be an `i` in the last pair of parentheses. As for lambdas: It is without the (double) lambdas construct at the very least ;) And the *double* in there makes me really shudder :)

Comment: @agf: Yes, 5 minutes have passed :)