# A loop within tkinter - HELP!

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my first time using this forum, hopefully, i can get a quick response with a detailed explanation.
Running:
Python 3.2
Tkinter 8.5 & Windows7 x64

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.lvl_one_att = 4
        self.bttn_clicks = 2
        self.bttn_clicks2 = 2
        self.bttn_clicks3 = 1
        self.bttn_clicks4 = 2
        self.bttn_clicks5 = 1
        self.bttn_clicks6 = 2
        self.bttn_clicks7 = 1
        self.bttn_clicks8 = 2
        self.bttn_clicks9 = 2
        self.level_one()
    def level_one(self):
        self.lbl1 = Label(self, text = "You must flip all the boxes to show the same colour!")
        self.lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.levellbl = Label(self, text = "Level 1")
        self.levellbl.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)
        self.rulesbttn = Button(self, text = "Instructions", command = self.rules)
        self.rulesbttn.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W, columnspan = 1)
        self.tlbttn = Button(self, bg = "red", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback1)
        self.tlbttn.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 1)
        self.tmbttn = Button(self, bg = "red", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback2)
        self.tmbttn.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 1)
        self.trbttn = Button(self, bg = "blue", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback3)
        self.trbttn.grid(row = 1, column = 2, columnspan = 1)
        self.mlbttn = Button(self, bg = "red", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback4)
        self.mlbttn.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 1)
        self.mmbttn = Button(self, bg = "blue", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback5)
        self.mmbttn.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 1)
        self.mrbttn = Button(self, bg = "red", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback6)
        self.mrbttn.grid(row = 2, column = 2, columnspan = 1)
        self.blbttn = Button(self, bg = "blue", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback7)
        self.blbttn.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 1)
        self.bmbttn = Button(self,  bg = "red",width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback8)
        self.bmbttn.grid(row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 1)
        self.brbttn = Button(self, bg = "red", width = 20, height = 10, command = self.callback9)
        self.brbttn.grid(row = 3, column = 2, columnspan = 1)
    def callback1(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change1()
        self.color_change2()
        self.color_change4()
        self.color_change5()
    def callback2(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change1()
        self.color_change2()
        self.color_change3()
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change4()
        self.color_change6()
    def callback3(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change2()
        self.color_change3()
        self.color_change6()
        self.color_change5()
    def callback4(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change1()
        self.color_change2()
        self.color_change4()
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change7()
        self.color_change8()
    def callback5(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change1()
        self.color_change2()
        self.color_change3()
        self.color_change6()
        self.color_change9()
        self.color_change4()
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change7()
        self.color_change8()
    def callback6(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change3()
        self.color_change2()
        self.color_change6()
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change9()
        self.color_change8()
    def callback7(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change4()
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change7()
        self.color_change8()
    def callback8(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change4()
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change6()
        self.color_change7()
        self.color_change8()
        self.color_change9()
    def callback9(self):
        self.lvl_one_att -= 1
        self.color_change5()
        self.color_change6()
        self.color_change9()
        self.color_change8()
    def color_change1(self):
        self.bttn_clicks += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks == 1:
            self.tlbttn.configure(bg = "blue") 
        else:
            self.tlbttn.configure(bg = "red")
    def color_change2(self):
        self.bttn_clicks2 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks2 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks2 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks2 == 1:
            self.tmbttn.configure(bg = "blue")  
        else:
            self.tmbttn.configure(bg = "red")  
    def color_change3(self):
        self.bttn_clicks3 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks3 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks3 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks3 == 1:
            self.trbttn.configure(bg = "blue")  
        else:
            self.trbttn.configure(bg = "red")  
    def color_change4(self):
        self.bttn_clicks4 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks4 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks4 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks4 == 1:
            self.mlbttn.configure(bg = "blue")   
        else:
            self.mlbttn.configure(bg = "red") 
    def color_change5(self):
        self.bttn_clicks5 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks5 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks5 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks5 == 1:
            self.mmbttn.configure(bg = "blue")  
        else:
            self.mmbttn.configure(bg = "red") 
    def color_change6(self):
        self.bttn_clicks6 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks6 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks6 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks6 == 1:
            self.mrbttn.configure(bg = "blue") 
        else:
            self.mrbttn.configure(bg = "red")   
    def color_change7(self):
        self.bttn_clicks7 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks7 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks7 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks7 == 1:
            self.blbttn.configure(bg = "blue")  
        else:
            self.blbttn.configure(bg = "red")  
    def color_change8(self):
        self.bttn_clicks8 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks8 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks8 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks8 == 1:
            self.bmbttn.configure(bg = "blue") 
        else:
            self.bmbttn.configure(bg = "red")
    def color_change9(self):
        self.bttn_clicks9 += 1
        if self.bttn_clicks9 == 3:
            self.bttn_clicks9 = 1
        if self.bttn_clicks9 == 1:
            self.brbttn.configure(bg = "blue")
        else:
            self.brbttn.configure(bg = "red")
    def rules(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Instructions", "The idea of the game, is to make sure all the boxes on the screen are the same colour. By pressing a button it will flip, all colours touching it, including diagonally. ")
    def round_win(self):
        self.lbl1.grid_forget()
        self.rulesbttn.grid_forget()
        self.tlbttn.grid_forget()
        self.tmbttn.grid_forget()
        self.trbttn.grid_forget()
        self.mlbttn.grid_forget()
        self.mmbttn.grid_forget()
        self.mrbttn.grid_forget()
        self.blbttn.grid_forget()
        self.bmbttn.grid_forget()
        self.brbttn.grid_forget()
        self.win()
    def win(self):
        self.lbl2 = Label(self, text = "CONGRATULATIONS!", font=("Helvetica", 40))
        self.lbl2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
root = Tk()
root.title("Program")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What i can work out how to do, is somehow use a loop so that when all 9 squares are the Red that it runs the round_win() function.
im unsure where to put the loop, and how to write it (for loop, while loop, if, but, else, etc)
Thanks heaps guys for any help you may be able to provide :)

Comment: i never said it was homework. i simply asked could somebody help with the loop part. ive done a buttload of looking, but nothing is clear and/or i cant stranslate it into my own code (from pseudo code or somebody else's example).

Comment: Homework or not, you need to rewrite this. Did you not ever think, as you were copying and pasting the exact same function ___nine times in a row___ that there might be a better way to do this?

Comment: yes i did. but i couldnt think of a way, and nobody i asked helped me, so did it my own way.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the original buttons into a list:

```
def level_one(self):
    ...
    self.game_buttons = []

    for btn_index in range(9):
        bg = "red" # change this to something based on the index
        next_button = Button(self, bg = bg, width = 20, height = 10)
        next_button['command'] = (lambda index=btn_index: self.callback(index))

        row = index/3 + 1
        column = index % 3
        next_button.grid(row = row, column = column, columnspan = 1)
        self.game_buttons.append(next_button)

def callback1(self, index):
    button = self.game_buttons[index]
    # add the appropriate code here

def color_change(self, index):
    # add the appropriate code here
```

Also, you can change the following code:

```
self.bttn_clicks2 += 1
    if self.bttn_clicks2 == 3:
        self.bttn_clicks2 = 1
```

to

```
self.bttn_clicks2 = self.bttn_clicks2 % 3 + 1
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but you need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737112/have-python-2-7-functions-remember-value-and-not-reference-closure-weirdness

Comment: changed to ...
    (lambda index=btn_index: self.callback(index))